# How to avoid DOM redraw when setting text with .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, dom

I have a clock on my web application which gets updated every few seconds with a call to $("#date").html(newTime);

My problem being that when using the site on mobile safari, if the user is attempting to correct their spelling when entering text into an input box - the list of corrections displays correctly but then disappears and switches to the 'copy/paste/define' options. Making it extremely difficult to make spelling corrections.

The problem happens everytime the clock is updated so I suspect its related to when the DOM is redrawn on .html() being called.

The following jsfiddle illustrates the problem:            http://www.jsfiddle.net/dadviegas/8x6mz/

```
function AddClock(element) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
            var now = new Date();
            var outStr = checklength(now.getHours()) + ':' + checklength(now.getMinutes()) + ':' + checklength(now.getSeconds());
            $(element).html(outStr);
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Go there on ipad/iphone, write a word in the HTML section and attempt to correct the spelling.

Any solutions to get around this problem??

Comment: Am not able to replicate but worst case you could stop updating the dom with time when and input is focused

Comment: Hi Charlie, what device/browser are you attempting to replicate on?

Comment: Ah that's a shame, its easily reproducible. I believe its a bug with iOS and must be happening on many sites. As stated your solution would work but only as a last resort.. Hoping for some more suggestions